# Double birthday problem

Tags: probability, birthday

I know the single coincidence has been thoroughly discussed here and elsewhere, but I happen to have a group of 20 close friends where we have not one but TWO birthday coincidences. Being the data artist in the group, I've decided to explore this and share. It is extremely unique, I believe, but how rare do probs say it is?

Comment: ...the probability of there being two coincidences, or this and the probability that they are in September and July?

Comment: I've to do the calculation, but my feeling is that it is not that rare at all, with a proba around 0.2 for $20$ randomly chosen people.

Comment: maybe think, what the singular probability of two people sharing a birthday are in 20 people. then think, about the singular probability that two people in 18 share a birthday.

Comment: For back-of the envelope calculations, the number of birthday coincidences is Poisson with mean $\lambda=\binom{20}{2}/365\approx .52$.  The chance of getting 2 coincidences is thus about $\exp(-\lambda)\lambda^2/2 \approx .08$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get exactly two matches (on different dates), the probability is:

$$\frac{{{365}\choose{2}}\cdot {{363}\choose{16}}\cdot{{20}\choose{2}}\cdot{{18}\choose{2}}\cdot16
! }{365^{20}}\approx .0713$$

Here is the reasoning for the numerator: Choose two dates of year for the matches.  Choose $16$ remaining dates for nonmatching birthdays.  Choose two of $20$ slots for the earlier match date.  Choose two of remaining $18$ slots for the later match date.  Make an arrangement of the $16$ unmatched dates in the remaining $16$ slots.

I ran a Python simulation one million times, and the results seemed in agreement.

Comment: It must be true if Python agrees! ;) brilliant icing on the cake of a clear answer! Kudos.

Comment: @SergioLucero Haha! Like my students say...if the calculator says $2+2=5$, then true it must be! Actually I was lazy and wrote the Python code first.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all $365$ birthdays are equally probable (ignoring leap years for example):

The probability that all birthdays are unique is $$1\times \frac {364}{365}\times \cdots \times \frac {365-19}{365}\approx 0.589$$

The probability that there is exactly one match is $$\binom {20}2\times \frac 1{365}\times \frac {364}{365}\times \cdots \times \frac {365-18}{365}\approx 0.323$$

Thus the probability that there are two or more matches is $$1-0.589-0.323\approx 0.088$$

Comment: I am not sure this answers the OP's question because your proba of 0.088 includes the case of 3 people having the same birthday and the 17 others have different ones.

Comment: @Evargalo  you may be right.  Of course, the same methodology easily covers the more specific case.  Perhaps the OP could clarify what was intended.

Answer (score 0):

Let's discard the 29th of February for simplification.

Number of cases: $365^{20}$

Number of cases without two birthsday at the same date: $365!/345!$

Number of cases with two birthsday at the same date and no other coincidence: $\binom{20}{2}*365!/346!$

Number of cases with two birthsday at one date, two birthdays and another date, and no other coincidence: 
$\binom{20}{2}\binom{18}{2}*365!/347!/2$